# range in sheet.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) also selecting blank rows although a filter was applied VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop all the non-hidden and non-blank rows in a sheet. The thing is, it does loop through the non-hidden but when it reaches the end of the non-hidden sheets, it just keeps going forever.

I know it retrieves 147 rows after the filter (including hidden rows) and it does skip them when doing the loop but, after it's done with the 147, it continues to 148 and so on, I have a validation to check if what it retrieved was blank and it stops there. I'd like it to stop at 147 or whatever number of rows throws the filter.

What I'm doing:

```
'I need the cells in B1 to begin with 0 or W, I guess I'd have to add a non-blank option (see below)

    With MaterialListSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="W*"
    End With

    Set rangeMaterialList = MaterialListSheet.Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count)

 For Each CellML In rangeMaterialList.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

       'Reset the variable in order to avoid unwanted codes
        BomCodesToSplit = ""
       'Check if there's a code in the cell
        If MaterialListSheet.Range("C" & CellML.Row & ":C" & CellML.Row).Value <> "" Then
            BomCodesToSplit = MaterialListSheet.Range("C" & CellML.Row & ":C" & CellML.Row).Value
        End If
        'Check if theres a code in the cell AND if it does concatenate (in case the variable isn't empty)

        If MaterialListSheet.Range("D" & CellML.Row & ":D" & CellML.Row).Value <> "" Then
           If BomCodesToSplit <> "" Then
                BomCodesToSplit = BomCodesToSplit & " / " & MaterialListSheet.Range("D" & CellML.Row & ":D" & CellML.Row).Value
            Else
                BomCodesToSplit = MaterialListSheet.Range("D" & CellML.Row & ":D" & CellML.Row).Value
           End If
        End If

        'Check if any BomCodes were retrieved
        If BomCodesToSplit = "" Then
           MsgBox "There was an error getting the Bom Codes", vbCritical, "Execution Terminated"
           End
        Else
            BomCodes = Split(BomCodesToSplit, "/")
        End If

   Next CellML
End Sub
```

The Filters I've tried:

```
'Im aware this doesn't work but decided to try it anyway
    With MaterialListSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="W*"
    End With
```

'I also realize this is not possible (I think)

```
With MaterialListSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="W*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria3:="<>"
End With
```

I don't even know if it's a filter thing, or maybe i'm missing something? I'm new to VBA and there's MANY things I don't know yet. All I want is to loop until (147 in this case, so it doesn't enter into the  `'Check if any BomCodes were retrieved` code.

Comment: instead of sheet special cells use the tables range special cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
Set rangeMaterialList = MaterialListSheet.Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count)
```

and **before any filtering is applied**, insert:

```
Dim N As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rangeMaterialList = MaterialListSheet.Range("B2:B" & N)
```

**EDIT #1**:

The coding you posted went too far down column B.  Nothing limited it to the table being filtered.  Without a limit, SpecialCells would all the way down to the bottom of UsedRange.

The change I suggested limited the range down to the bottom of data in column B.

The reason I specified it be done **before** the filter is applied is that End(xlup) may not work on filtered data.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, could you please explain me what does that do and why before the filters?

Comment: Also, what's the difference between Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row and MaterialListSheet.Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count)

Comment: @Splendonia `Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count)` counts all the rows in column B whereas `Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` counts all the rows in column B and then returns the last row in the column with data (similar to a `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Up`)

Comment: @ARich : Thanks for the comment.  a critical point is Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row counts all the rows in column B and then returns the last row in the column with **visible** data